# How to use cell fracture?

Tags: add-on

Seriously, how to use it? Because no matter what I do, I get an unusable mess. (Blender 2.81)
Edit: I did manually now, someone may correct me but it seems not working with spherical objects... (I increased the verts count up to 50 000 and made a perfect sphere and still holes and overlaps)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't seem to have a particle system in your setup. Try "Own Verts" instead of "Own Particles" in the Cell Fracture window. Also, you might use a higher subdiv value for your icosphere - or a "rounded cube" (cube with subdiv > 3, then go to edit mode, type "To Sphere" in the search bar and drag your mouse to the right) to get better results.

Comment: mhh doesn't seem to work with spheres at all. Changed to own verts, Bumbed it up to 50 000 vert, made a perfect sphere and increased source limit up 500 and I've still holes and overlaps... By the time now, I already did it manually.